# Store the return string to a variable for zenity

Tags: linux, bash, zenity

I am using Zenity tool to pop-up an entry dialog box. But how can i store the value entered into the text box to a variable ? Now, the string is being printed onto the console itself. I want it to be stored into a variable to process it !

Answer (score 3):

Use command substitution:

```
reply=$(zenity --entry)
```

Comment: Note that this method is also the way to process multiple form fields from `zenity` (option `--forms`). It is up to you to split this single string into multiple variables, and the `--separator` option helps.

Answer (score 1):

To assign value of output wrap your command with $(command) and assigne it to variable

```
 VALUE=$(zenity --entry)
```